# Help with model selection

Tags: multivariate-analysis, model, matrix

In my experimental setup, I have a square symmetric matrix of variables (65) which I'll call A.  Aij represents some relationship between the variables. I then performed an experiment in which I have a different measurement for the exact same variables, call it B. I would like to know how I could model this data if my goal it to predict the value of B based on the values of A.

Any suggestions or a push in the right direction would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Why are the variables in a matrix?  Why not a vector?